# String Concatenation - valueOf or not

Tags: java, string

So I just perused for a while, all the different questions on here about `.valueOf` with strings, but they all seem to be about conversions. Comparing `.valueOf` to just + `""`.

I want to know if it is worth it or at all necessary to use `.valueOf` if it is a concatenation.

**Example:**

```
LOGGER.info("Final Score: " + String.valueOf(Math.round(finalScore * 100)) + "%");
```

**VS**

```
LOGGER.info("Final Score: " + Math.round(finalScore * 100) + "%");
```

It seems as though using `String.valueOf` is unnecessary if you have actual strings to go along with it. I understand it may be better to use `.valueOf` if you were just converting it and intended to use an empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we concatenate strings, the compiler actually translates it to [StringBuffer.append()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4343/abebh/index.html).

The underlying implementations for [StringBuffer.append(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.append%28int%29) and [String.valueOf(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28int%29) both eventually end up calling [Integer.getChars(int,int,char[])](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.getChars%28int%2Cint%2Cchar%5B%5D%29) except that in case of `String.valueOf()`, there is a call to `Integer.toString(int)` first.

To conclude, for the given scenario, directly concatenating would be the way to go. But if you intend to be conscious about memory, then use string-builder to concatenate values first and then log it.

Comment: So even if you were to use one of those two methods instead of the direct concatenation, StringBuffer.append would actually be better because it takes one less step?

Comment: Yes, since in this case you'd be helping the compiler not having to do it again.

Answer (score 2):

The source code for `String#valueOf(Object)` looks like this:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

So the only difference between `valueOf` and `toString` is that `valueOf` is null-safe. So let's see which one is used if we concatenate a string and an object.

```
Object foo = null;
System.out.println("foo " + foo); //foo null, no exception thrown
System.out.println("foo " + String.valueOf(foo)); //foo null, no exception thrown
```

So it looks like there's no difference whatsoever between concatenation and using `valueOf` in this context.

Comment: So in the case where you have output text already, valueOf would just be more code in the line, but not doing anything different since it would already use the toString behind the scenes. Making it kind of redundant?

Comment: I'd agree with that, yes.

Answer (score 0):

you are correct. When you are combining strings and other datatypes, the valueOf is not necessary. For only an int, I think the valueOf works, but anecdotally, the 2nd example is a lot more common

```
@Test
public void testStringValueOF(){
    int num = 123;

    // this works...
    String test = String.valueOf(num);

    // but this is more common
    String test2 = "" + num;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to know in the context adding another value type onto actual strings, not just empty strings to be used for conversion.